# Error de parseo al aplicar JSON.stringfy en el body en una peticion fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, json, fetch

Estoy montando una llamada con javascript usando fetch y pasando como estructura en el body un JSON.stringfy pero me esta dando problemas a la hora de parsear...

Uso esta estructura para la llamada :

```
 method: "POST", 
 body: JSON.stringify(datos),
 headers: {
     "Content-Type" : "application/json"
 }
```

Donde "datos" tiene una estructura json :

```
let datos = {nombre:"User",apellido:"Default",email:"userdefault@gmail.com",telefono:"654-554-432"};
```

Observando la salida que me devuelve al hacer la peticion, me indica este mensaje de error...

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
```

Esta seria la estructura completa del fecth :

```
let datos = {nombre:"User",apellido:"Default",email:"userdefault@gmail.com",telefono:"654-554-432"};
fetch("../index.php",{
     method: "POST", 
     body: JSON.stringify(datos),
     headers: {
         "Content-Type" : "application/json"
     }
 })
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data =>data)
```

Esta es la estructura php que valida las cabeceras y el decode de la peticion :

```
<?php

    header("Content-type:aplication/json");
    require "./includes/db.php";
    $msg_error = ["resultado" => "error"]; 

    if(!$error_db){
        if($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] == "application/json" && $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true)){
                $respuesta = ["resultado" => "ko"]; 
                switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]){
                    case "POST": 
                        require "./vistas/crear.php";
                    break;
                    case "PUT": 
                        require "vistas/actualizar.php";
                    break;
                    case "DELETE": 
                        require "vistas/borrar.php";
                    break;
                    default:
                        echo json_encode($msg_error);
                    break;
                }
            }else{
                echo json_encode($msg_error);
            }
        }
?>
```

¿Estoy usando la forma correcta para parsear con JSON.stringfy? ¿Que podria estar fallando en la peticion, cabecera, JSON.parse?

Comment: ¿Podrías acceder al inspector de red del navegador y ver el contenido de la respuesta? Tiene toda la pinta que el script PHP está generando algún tipo de mensaje de advertencia que no está en JSON. En la mayoría de navegadores accedes a él usando las opciones de depuración (pulsando la tecla `F12`) en una pestaña llamada *Red* o *Network*. Luego pulsas en la petición y en la pestaña vista previa o preview podrás ver el contenido de la respuesta.

Comment: Haciendo debbug este es el contenido de la respuesta con un error 500 :
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" y respuesta "VGhlIGNvbm5lY3Rpb24gaGFzIGJlZW4gc3VjY2Vzc2Z1bGx5IGVzdGFibGlzaGVk" no me queda muy claro que puede estar pasando en el parseo...

Comment: entonces lo que está fallando es `res => res.json()` porque el servidor no responde con un JSON válido

Comment: Cambiando res => res.json() por res.text() tambien indica el mismo error... Cual seria la forma correcta de parsear el JSON a String y resolver la promesa ?

Comment: Por favor, sigue mis instrucciones y usa el inspector de red para ver el contenido de la respuesta en texto plano. Está claro que el problema está en que el script PHP no está generando un JSON válido, y eso podría ser por múltiples motivos.

Comment: Viendo el comentario, parece que está devolviendo algo en base64. ¿Podías compartir la parte del código PHP en la que generas la salida JSON?

Comment: Recuerda nombrarme con @ para que me notifique que has hecho la edición que te pedí. Solo falta conocer el contenido de la respuesta, mirando en el inspector de red. Como pequeña mejora, cambia `Content-type:aplication/json` por `Content-Type: application/json` (un espacio en blanco después de los dos puntos y una P adicional en application).

Comment: Buenas, al final era un tema del propio navegador, manteniendo la misma estructura logramos realizar inserts en formato String Json con JSON.Stringfy, muchas gracias a todos los que participaron en la solucion.